# Supervised learning linear regression

Tags: machine-learning

I am confused about how linear regression works in supervised learning. Now I want to generate a evaluation function for a board game using linear regression, so I need both the input data and output data. Input data is my board condition, and I need the corresponding value for this condition, right? But how can I get this expected value? Do I need to write an evaluation function first by myself? But I thought I need to generate an evluation function by using linear regression, so I'm a little confused about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *supervised-learning* after all, meaning: you will need input and output.

Now the question is: how to obtain these? And this is not trivial!

Candidates are:

- historical-data (e.g. online-play history)
- some form or self-play / reinforcement-learning (more complex)

But then a new problem arises: which output is available and what kind of input will you use.

If there would be some a-priori implemented AI, you could just take the scores of this one. But with historical-data for example you only got -1,0,1 (A wins, draw, B wins) which makes learning harder (and this touches the *Credit Assignment problem*: there might be one play which made someone lose; it's hard to understand which of 30 moves lead to the result of 1). This is also related to the input. Take chess for example and take a random position from some online game: there is the possibility that this position is unique over 10 million games (or at least not happening often) which conflicts with the expected performance of your approach. I assumed here, that the input is the full board-position. This changes for other inputs, e.g. chess-material, where the input is just a histogram of pieces (3 of these, 2 of these). Now there are much less unique inputs and learning will be easier.

Long story short: it's a complex task with a lot of different approaches and most of this is somewhat bound by your exact task! A linear evaluation-function is not super-uncommon in reinforcement-learning approaches. You might want to read some literature on these (this function is a core-component: e.g. table-lookup vs. linear-regression vs. neural-network to approximate the value- or policy-function).

I might add, that your task indicates the *self-learning* approach to AI, which is very hard and it's a topic which somewhat gained additional (there was success before: see Backgammon AI) popularity in the last years. But all of these approaches are highly complex and a good understanding of RL and the mathematical-basics like Markov-Decision-Processes are important then.

For more classic hand-made evaluation-function based AIs, a lot of people used an additional regressor for tuning / weighting already implemented components. Some overview at [chessprogramming wiki](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Automated%20Tuning). (the chess-material example from above might be a good one: assumption is: more pieces better than less; but it's hard to give them values)